# How to understand monad in scala

Tags: scala, monads, higher-kinded-types

I just understood what type constructor and higher kinded types states for and now I'm trying to understand Monad. Here is how `Monad` trait looks in `scalaz`:

```
trait Monad[F[_]] extends Applicative[F] with Bind[F] { self =>
  ////

  override def map[A,B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B) = bind(fa)(a => point(f(a)))
  //The rest is omitted

}
```

The question is I don't kind of understand why `Monad` is a higher kinded type? We have standard `List[T]`, `Option[T]` monads which are not higher kinded types.

I'm not a Theory Category expert so I treat monad as a container with monads laws.

Why don't we just declare a monad as follows:

```
trait Monad[V]{
    //...
}
```

Not a higher kind.

How would standard `Option[T]` monad look like in that case as a a subclass for instance?

Comment: In short, assume monad just another pattern, which unify data manipulation under scala collection library.

Comment: @Pavel Okay, but why is it higher kinded type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala Functor and Monad differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460594/scala-functor-and-monad-differences)

Comment: They sometimes say "a monad is like a burrito" :)

Comment: my personal understanding its because its abstraction over abstraction,  only one reason I can find.

Comment: @Pavel Yes, that's what higher-kind type definition states for :). But how coould we implement a standard `Option` monad?

Comment: A monad consists of a type constructor (e.g. `Option`, `List` etc.) and the functions `pure` and `bind`/`join`. The monad trait needs to have a higher kind to abstract over the type constructors.

Comment: @Lee Ah... it seems in scalaz Monad actually a normal Functor which acts on some category. So we need to abstract over category. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not a category theory expert, but no I don't think monads abstract over categories. My understanding is a monad is a functor along with two natural transformations. In the scala encoding, the monad instance is parameterised by the functor so you would say `Monad[Option]`, `Monad[List]` etc. Since those type constructors have kind `* -> *` the monad trait needs to specify that in the definition. With your example you wouldn't be able to write `pure[A](x: A): V[A]` since `V` does not have the right kind.

Comment: You don't abstract over categories with a Monad, in the categorical sense. Generally, when we're talking about a category in terms of programming, we're talking about the category of types and functions. This makes all functors in Scala in fact endo-functors. Think of it this way, if Functor let's you put things inside a box, a Monad let's you not only put them in a box, but also to unwrap a box inside a box, meaning `M[M[A] => M[A]`. This is what `bind` actually does, it gets a function `A => M[B]` and then unwraps the inner container by called `join`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't kind of understand why Monad is a higher
>   kinded type?

I think the fastest way to see why it has to be a higher kinded type is to try and create a signature for `pure` where the type parameter isn't itself a type constructor:

```
// Doesn't compile
trait Monad[V]{
  def pure[A](a: A): V[A]
}
```

Of course, that doesn't work because we can't write `V[A]` for an arbitrary type parameter, it has to be a type constructor, particularly one of kind `* -> *`

> How would standard Option[T] monad look like in that case as a
>   subclass for instance

Another thing about a Monad (and a Functor for that matter) being a type constructor is that we create a single representation of `Monad[List]`, for example, and get it for free for all `T` arguments of that `List` because of polymorphic types and theorms for free. Again, you could not by the virtue of the signature of `Monad` implement it without a type constructor.

> We have standard List[T], Option[T] monads which are not higher kinded
>   types.

That's right. They are not higher kinded because `T` itself isn't required to be a type constructor for any operations of `List[T]` or `Option[T]` to work, but `T` in that sense can represent any type. This means that although `Option[T]` is of kind `* -> *`, I can still construct it with a `List` to produce a `Option[List[T]]`.